# How to return multiple forloop results (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have function to return list of hotels:

```
def search_result(request): 
    ......
    for hotels in json_data.get('hotelList'):
        hotel = hotels.get('localizedName')
        print hotel

    return HttpResponse(hotel)
```

in console it prints whole list:

```
     ....
    Apex Temple Court Hotel
    The Connaught
    Corinthia Hotel London
    London House Hotel
    The Royal Park Hotel
    The Dorchester Hotel
    The Royal Horseguards
```

but returns only the last one 'The Royal Horseguards'. 
JsonResponse() also returns the last record.
What method should I use to return full list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a list and then return it.

```
def search_result(request): 
    ......
    results = []
    for hotels in json_data.get('hotelList'):
        results.append(hotels.get('localizedName'))


    return HttpResponse(results)
```

To display the contents properly, you need to use a template, and not just `HttpResponse`.

Create a template like this, and save it for example `hotels.html`:

```
{% if hotels %}
  <ul>
  {% for hotel in hotels %}
     <li>{{ hotel }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Now, in your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def search_result(request): 
    ......
    results = []
    for hotels in json_data.get('hotelList'):
        results.append(hotels.get('localizedName'))


    return render(request, 'hotels.html', {'hotels': results})
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, Burhan! But  it prints solid line, how to split it by titles?

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko `print '\n'.join(results)` if you just want to print with separate line or did you mean the template?

Comment: Now it actually prints with separate lines, without .join(), but i want it to be separated in template.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to return the whole list instead the content of last read and assigned hotel?

```
json_data.get('hotelList')
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me because 'localizedName' is nested in 'hotelList'